# What does case _: c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax, switch-statement

I was dissecting a unity plugin and came across a `switch` statement I do not fully understand. I googled it but came up a blank. does anybody know / can explain what  `case _:` means?

Comment: Can you show the entire relevant code. I can't get `case _:` compiled, unless `_` has been used as a constant name: `const string _ = "";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) - it's a placeholder variable for a value you don't care about and never intend to use. C# can optimize these values out and refrain from allocating memory for them.

Comment: Such a case statement doesn't compile unless a constant `_` was declared (having precedence over discard). It works with a type pattern, however: `case Person _:` but the discard is obsolete, as you can simply write `case Person:`.